# Running nunit test with specific data

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I have a test that takes in test data. When using nunit console app to run the test, is there a way I can specify the data to be used?

Eg:

```
[Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(TestData))]
public void ATest(string param1, int param2)

public class TestData : IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new object[] { "blah1 blah1", 1};
        yield return new object[] { "blah2 blah2", 2};
    }
}
```

I want to be able to run ATest with test data ["blah2 blah2", 2] only. If I run as follows:

```
nunit3-console.exe Tests.dll --test=ATest --workers=1 --noresult
```

it will run twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run...

nunit3-console.exe Tests.dll --test ATest("blah2 blah2", 2)

or

nunit3-console.exe Tests.dll --where "test~=blah2"

If that string is unique to all your tests.

Note that the first one may require some escaping of the quotes, depending on your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be through returning a `TestCaseData` object instead.

Something like this: (untested, so syntax might be a little off!)

```cs
[Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(TestData))]
public void ATest(string param1, int param2)

public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    yield return new TestCaseData("blah1 blah1", 1).SetName("FirstTest");
    yield return new TestCaseData("blah2 blah2", 2).SetName("SecondTest");
}
```

To run the first test, you would then use the command line:

```
nunit3-console.exe Tests.dll --test=YourNameSpace.ATest.FirstTest --workers=1 --noresult
```

Depending what you're doing, setting the category may be more suitable than the name. The docs page shows what's available: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData